# Assign value to column from preceding column

Tags: r

Basically the "Counts" column is the difference between the number of days 
  thus resulting in zero for all Day 1's. I'd like to replace 0 in the counts 
  column with the data in Day 1.

```
 Sample Data 
  Unique ID   Day    Total Counts   Color  Counts
   123        Day 1       12           Red    0
   123        Day 2       14           Red    2
   123        Day 3       17           Red    3
   123        Day 4       21           Red    4
   133        Day 1       10           Red    0
   133        Day 2       14           Red    4
   133        Day 3       17           Red    3
   133        Day 4       22           Red    5
   133        Day 3       25           Red    3
   133        Day 5       30           Red    5
```

what I'd like to have

```
  Unique ID   Day    Total Counts   Color  Counts
   123        Day 1       12           Red    12
   123        Day 2       14           Red    2
   123        Day 3       17           Red    3
   123        Day 4       21           Red    4
   133        Day 1       10           Red    10
   133        Day 2       14           Red    4
   133        Day 3       17           Red    3
   133        Day 4       22           Red    5
   133        Day 3       25           Red    3
   133        Day 5       30           Red    5
```

Comment: Try `df[df$Counts == 0, 'Counts'] <- df[df$Counts == 0, 'Total Counts']`

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- read.table(text = "UniqueID   Day    TotalCounts   Color  Counts
                  123       Day1       12           Red    0
                 123        Day2       14           Red    2
                 123        Day3       17           Red    3
                 123        Day4       21           Red    4
                 123        Day1       10           Red    0
                 123        Day2       14           Red    4
                 123        Day3       17           Red    3
                 123        Day4       22           Red    5
                 123        Day3       25           Red    3
                 123        Day5       30           Red    5", 
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[Counts == 0, Counts := TotalCounts]


    UniqueID  Day TotalCounts Color Counts
 1:      123 Day1          12   Red     12
 2:      123 Day2          14   Red      2
 3:      123 Day3          17   Red      3
 4:      123 Day4          21   Red      4
 5:      123 Day1          10   Red     10
 6:      123 Day2          14   Red      4
 7:      123 Day3          17   Red      3
 8:      123 Day4          22   Red      5
 9:      123 Day3          25   Red      3
10:      123 Day5          30   Red      5
```

Comment: It is difficult to see how this improves on the answer in the comments (at least for datasets < 100K observations). However, to improve your answer, the `df <- ` in `df <- df[Counts == 0, Counts := TotalCounts]` is unecessary as the `:=` operator assigns by reference, so `df[Counts == 0, Counts := TotalCounts]` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know it's not necessary to use `<-` while using `:=`. I have modified that part.

Comment: Great. A large part of the speed advantage in `data.table` is its ability to avoid copies. `<-` produces a copy of it's left hand side, which greatly affects the advantage of using that package in this example.